# setOnTouchListener header listview android not working

Tags: android, listview

I have a `ListView`, and I add header for the `ListView`, but when I use `setOnTouchListener` for the header it seems not working.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.event_list, container, false);
    btnLoadMore = inflater.inflate(R.layout.event_list_footer, null, false);
    listEvent = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list_event);
    mHeader = inflater.inflate(R.layout.event_list_header, null, false);
    listEvent.addHeaderView(mHeader,null, false);
    listEvent.addFooterView(btnLoadMore);
    mHeader.setOnTouchListener(mActivitySwipeMotion);
    return rootView;
}
```

and event_list_header.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image_banner"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:src="@drawable/banner_evenlist" />
```

Comment: Can you post event_list_header layout?

Comment: ok,layout header: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_banner"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/banner_evenlist" />
    

</LinearLayout>

Answer (score 0):

**try this**

```
enter code here

<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/myList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    Then add the header layout to your ListView:

View header = (View)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.header,null);
mList.addHeaderView(header);
```

Comment: Hi, i want detect event ontouch for header

Comment: you make one xml file which is called header.xml, then set header on that file and try this code.

Comment: any problem? Let me know.

Comment: i added header, but i want set setOnTouchListener  for header. examble: header.setOnTouchListener (this). But seem it not working